# Android Skobbler Maps startup location

Tags: android, skmaps

I tried the demo for Skobbler Android integration. When I start this demo it always locate me somewhere in Germany, no matter where I am.

What is the options for control the startup location (map)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default is set to start in Berlin. If you want to change that you have to make the changes in the demo project:

```
 // centers the map on a specific position
mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate(-122.430337, 37.779776));


// centers the map on current position
mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate( currentPosition.getLongitude(), currentPosition.getLatitude()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `centerMapOnPosition()` is not available in SDK 3.0.2, which currently is the newest SDK. Having said that, you can control the startup location by:

1. `setPositionAsCurrent()`, for instance:

   ```
   mapView.setPositionAsCurrent(new SKCoordinate(51.5085300, -0.1257400), 0, true); 

   setPositionAsCurrent(SKCoordinate gpsCorrdinates, float accuracy, boolean centerMap)
   ```

   Displays the position on the map with the blue dot, with the possibility to center the map. Then you need to remove the blue dot by using:

   ```
   mapView.getMapSettings().setCurrentPositionShown(false);
   ```
2. `animateToLocation()`, for instance:

   ```
   mapView.animateToLocation(new SKCoordinate(51.5085300, -0.1257400), 100);

   public void animateToLocation(SKCoordinate position,int duration)
   ```

   Centers the map in the specified position smoothly.

[Here](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSurfaceView.html) is a link to the newest documentation.